# AlertDialog is shown before methods insde thread finished Android Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

The first activity in the app checks if tables and data are loaded correctly before launching the main activity.

If not, it connects to server using volley and loads the data and images and then asks user to restart app.

The problem is: `AlertDialog` is shown with "message loading complete" directly before the methods finished loading.

I created a thread inside the `onCreate` method and put all methods inside it but the same problem persists.

My question is: How can I show the `alertDialog` after methods complete data loading?

Here is my code:

```
    if(! (checkTables()&&checkData())){
        progressDialog.show();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                fillSamples();
                fillExams();
                fillQuestions();
                fillSubQuestions();
            }
        }).start();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this);
        builder.setMessage("Loading Data Complete Please restart your App");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: if i use handler i have to determine time in milliseconds but  loading time is not fixed it depends on internet speed so i can not user handler for this purpose

Comment: i have updated the answer please check

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AsyncTask instead of Thread. For more info [Threads and AsyncTask](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

```
if(! (checkTables()&&checkData())){
    GetData.execute();
}
class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Add your progress dialog.
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this);
            builder.setMessage("Loading Data Complete Please restart your App");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        fillSamples();
        fillExams();
        fillQuestions();
        fillSubQuestions();
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the same issue my code and yours running and what is in thread is done but the problem is showing alert dialog before methods finish their jobs

Comment: In that case, you need to make use of `isAlive()` of Thread and write some listeners for the same.